# Parametrization

Tags: calculus, parametrization

How do I parametrize the attached problems. I am a bit confused because it is not in a typical format that can be easily parametrized.[image]

Comment: So the region $\mathcal{D}$ is actually given as $\mathcal{R}$...? That's four times a rectangle, you parametrize all the four sides (in each case).

Comment: That may be why I'm so confused. Does it seem like R is the domain from the question?

Comment: I suppose that's what they mean: calculate the line integrals over the _boundary_ of the given regions $\mathcal{R}$ (all rectangles) and verify that result by also using Green's Theorem (i.e. calculating a double integral over $\mathcal{R}$).

Comment: Correction: the first three are rectangles, the fourth region is a triangle (I looked over the variable boundary $x$ in the limits for $y$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work out one example to get you started; I'll take (d).

The region $\mathcal{R}$ is the triangle connecting $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(1,1)$. You need to parametrize the three sides; I'll choose parametrizations in such a way that the parameter $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$ in all cases:

- the segment connecting  $A$ and $B$:$$\vec r_1 = (t,0)$$
- the segment connecting  $B$ and $C$:$$\vec r_2 = (1,t)$$
- the segment connecting  $C$ and $A$:$$\vec r_3 = (1-t,1-t)$$

Then:
$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\mathcal{C}}xy^2dx+x^2ydy & =\int_{{AB}}xy^2dx+x^2ydy+\int_{{BC}}xy^2dx+x^2ydy+\int_{{CA}}xy^2dx+x^2ydy \\[8pt]
& =\int_0^1 t0^2dt+t^20d0+\int_0^1t^2d1+tdt+\int_0^1(1-t)^3d(1-t)+(1-t)^3d(1-t) \\[8pt]
& =\int_0^1 \left( t -2(1-t)^3\right) dt\\[8pt]
& = \ldots
\\[8pt]
& =0
\end{align}$$

This is easily verified with Green's theorem since:
$$\frac{\partial (x^2y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial y} = 2xy-2xy = 0$$
So clearly:
$$\oint_{\mathcal{C}}xy^2dx+x^2ydy = \iint_{\mathcal{R}} \frac{\partial (x^2y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial y} \, dydx = \int_0^1 \int_0^x 0 \, dydx = 0$$

Comment: Could you have picked C to A to just be (t, t) or was there a reason you picked 1-t for both components?

Comment: I picked it so the parameter $t$ would run from $0$ to $1$ as well (allowing to take the integrals together as one integral in $t$ with the same limits).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Had you made both components t, what would the bounds look like for C to A.

Comment: They would run from $t=1$ (since that would correspond to point $C$ if you pick that parametrization) to $t=0$ (corresponding to $A$) which may seem a bit unnatural. You can then however flip the limits of integration by adding an extra minus-sign: $\int_1^0 \cdots = -\int_0^1 \ldots$.

Comment: Oh, alright. That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!